# get full file uploaded path in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a question about file upload. i want to print the original filepath as it was on the users PC (eg 'C:\Documents and settings\guest\documents\test.txt')
i have try some method but only get filename.. i need to print full path

```
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;


    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

echo "C:\Documents and settings\guest\documents\test.txt"; //get full path 
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Short answer is you can't. You could ask the user to supply that information but the server does not know where it comes from and shouldn't know.

Comment: There are some experimental and not-widely-supported javascript methods like `webkitGetAsEntry` which can show the users filesystem of a file-drop event... but that sort of thing is ... as I said... not widely supported and not for production.